# Python to add data label on linechart from Matplotlib and Pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am hoping to add data labels to a line chart produced by Matplotlib from Pandas GroupBy.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO(
"""
Name    Year - Month    Score
Mike    2022-09 192
Mike    2022-08 708
Mike    2022-07 140
Mike    2022-05 144
Mike    2022-04 60
Mike    2022-03 108
Kate    2022-07 19850
Kate    2022-06 19105
Kate    2022-05 23740
Kate    2022-04 19780
Kate    2022-03 15495
Peter   2022-08 51
Peter   2022-07 39
Peter   2022-06 49
Peter   2022-05 49
Peter   2022-04 79
Peter   2022-03 13
Lily    2022-11 2
David   2022-11 3
David   2022-10 6
David   2022-08 2""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

for group_name, sub_frame in df.groupby("Name"):
    if sub_frame.shape[0] >= 2:
        sub_frame_sorted = sub_frame.sort_values('Year - Month')       # sort the data-frame by a column

        line_chart = sub_frame_sorted.plot("Year - Month", "Score")

        label = sub_frame_sorted['Score']
        line_chart.annotate(label, (sub_frame_sorted['Year - Month'], sub_frame_sorted['Score']), ha='center') 

plt.show()
```

The 2 lines for data labels throw an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I have them corrected?

Comment: Which two line gives you the error?  While constructing the "df"?

Comment: @MostafaShaminYeasar, thanks for the comment. "line_chart.annotate(label, (sub_frame_sorted['Year - Month'], sub_frame_sorted['Score']), ha='center')", is the problematic line.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says that the problem is in the `annotate()`. The `sub_frame_sorted` is a dataframe and you need to use a `for` loop to get each of the items within it before using annotate. Also, the x-axis is year-month, which is seen as string and you will run into issues. So, you need to just use index. I have used  0,1,2... using `i`. This should work... you can add a small offset if you think the text is overlapping a line
Hope this is what you are looking for.

**Updated code**

```
for group_name, sub_frame in df.groupby("Name"):
    if sub_frame.shape[0] >= 2:
        sub_frame_sorted = sub_frame.sort_values('Year - Month')       # sort the data-frame by a column
        line_chart = sub_frame_sorted.plot("Year - Month", "Score", legend=False)
        i=0
        for ix, vl in sub_frame_sorted.iterrows(): 
            line_chart.annotate(vl['Score'], (i, vl['Score']), ha='center') 
            i=i+1
plt.show()
```

**Output plots**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks! but when I adapted your code, and try to remove the legend by "line_chart.get_legend().remove()", it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
"

Comment: You can try `legend=False` INSIDE the `sub_frame_sorted.plot()` ... like this - `line_chart = sub_frame_sorted.plot("Year - Month", "Score", legend=False)`. That worked for me

Comment: Updated answer and plots with the same...

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem should be inside your for loop.

You can replace your code by this one:

```
for group_name, sub_frame in df.groupby("Name"):
    if sub_frame.shape[0] >= 2:
        sub_frame_sorted = sub_frame.sort_values('Year - Month')

        line_chart = sub_frame_sorted.plot("Year - Month", "Score")
        for x, y in zip(sub_frame_sorted["Year - Month"], sub_frame_sorted["Score"]):
            label = "{:.0f}".format(y)  # format the label as a string
            line_chart.annotate(label, (x, y), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0,10), ha='center')
```

And also if you face error regarding 'Year-Month' you should convert that using to_datetime() method.

Please let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Comment: thanks! but when I adapted your code, with "Year-Month" converted by "sub_frame_sorted['Year - Month'] = pd.to_datetime(sub_frame_sorted['Year - Month'], format='%Y-%m')", and try to remove the legend by "line_chart.get_legend().remove()", it says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
"

Comment: thanks for the feedback. you just need to add legend=False like the accepted answer to remove the legend. I think my code will also serve your purpose :)